# Functions from empty set in Coq

Tags: coq

I am new to Coq. I noticed it was possible to define the empty set in Coq using

```
Inductive Empty_set : Set :=.
```

Is it also possible to define the function from the empty set to another general set/type ?
If so how ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Just use pattern matching:

```
Definition of_Empty_set T (x : Empty_set) : T :=
  match x with end.
```